# AIR for iOS convert timestamp in days hours seconds

Tags: actionscript-3, time

I have ios app running its running on android as well.
i have written code to convert timestamp into days and hours and minutes but its not working properly when i deploy on iOS

Here is my code:

```
public function getFeedTime(str:Number = 0):String
        {
            //str = 1366984611;
            var currentDate:Date = new Date();
            var currentTime:Number = new Date().getTime();
            var dateFromServer:Date = new Date(str*1000);
            var timeDifference:Number = (currentTime - (str*1000))/1000;
            var rtn:String = "a moment ago";
            rtn = dateFromServer.toLocaleDateString();
            var bsameDay:Boolean = false;
            if ( dateFromServer.date == currentDate.date && dateFromServer.month ==  currentDate.month && dateFromServer.fullYear ==  currentDate.fullYear )
            {
                if(timeDifference >3600)
                {
                    var H:Number = Math.round(timeDifference/3600);
                    if(H>1)
                        rtn = H+" hrs ago";
                    else
                        rtn = H+" hr ago";      
                }else if(timeDifference >=120)
                {
                    var M:Number = Math.round(timeDifference/60); 
                    if(M>1)
                        rtn = M+" mins ago";
                    else
                        rtn = "1 min ago";  
                }
                else if(timeDifference >59 && timeDifference < 120)
                {    
                    rtn = "1 min ago";    
                }else if(timeDifference <59){
                    rtn = "a moment ago";
                }
                bsameDay = true;

            }
            if ( bsameDay == false)
            {

                rtn =  Math.round((timeDifference/3600)/24).toString();
                if(Number(rtn) <= 1){
                    rtn = rtn + " Day ago"
                }else
                {
                    rtn = rtn + " Days ago"
                }
            }

            return rtn;    
        }
```

Somehow when running on iOS if time stamp is lesser than 24 hours lets say 1hr 30 minutes it says 0 days ago but in android it says 1 hour 30 minutes

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add a trace(timeDifference); after it's computed to see if there's a difference.  If so I would trace(currentTime) between the two platforms (in fact just trace everything relevant to the computation).  My broad guestimation would say this is maybe something related to daily savings time(DST) differences, possibly a bug. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html#version <- could check platform and adjust if it's consistent.

Comment: daylight saving time* rather